# Using Linq.Dynamic where method with a dynamic list gives error

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, dynamic-linq

I am reading some JSON and converting it to a dynamic list.
Below is My Code:

```
dynamic data = JObject.Parse(response);
var result = data.result;
var result = ((IEnumerable)arr).Cast<dynamic>().ToList();

var id = result[0].id;
var filtereddata = result.Where("id==1");
```

The line

```
var filtereddata = result.Where("id==1");
```

Gives error `No property or field 'id' exists in type 'Object` while `var id = result[0].id;` seems to be working.

The JSON I am parsing is :

```
{
"count": 1,
"result": [
{
  "id": 11,
  "name": "Locations",

}]
}
```

Please let me know if more information is needed. Thanks for your valuable time.

**Edit:**
Even tried `var filtereddata = result.Where(c=>c.id==1).Select("id");` using lambda expression but still the same issue.

Comment: I don't think Dynamic LINQ works with `dynamic` types.

Comment: Why dynamic? Why not poco? http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: I cannot use poco and exacts fields can vary. So have to use dynamic. If there is any solution other then Dynamic Linq I can check that as well

Comment: How about regular LINQ? e.g. `Where(x => x.id == 1)`.

Comment: Actually I have the where condition as a string "id==1". So that is why I was using the Dynamic Linq

Comment: It does not work with regular LINQ as well. Please check the edit

Comment: You are still using Dynamic LINQ, this time the `Select`.

Comment: One point is when Sql based filtering i done it shall not be `==`, which is a programming logical operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic LINQ does not work with `dynamic` type. LINQ to Objects would work, but since you are receiving the filter as `string`, it's not applicable.

The workaround is to use temporary anonymous projection before applying the dynamic `Where` and then selecting back the original object:

```
var filtereddata = result
    .Select(x => new { item = x, id = (int)x.id, name = (string)x.name })
    .Where("id==1")
    .Select(x => x.item);
```

Comment: If anonymous projection to a well defined is feasible, then why create `IEnumerable<dynamic>` in first place, can directly create a schema post Json read

Comment: @MrinalKamboj I have no idea why OP has chosen to parse into `JObject` which internally creates `dynamic` `JArray` / `JObject` / `JProperty`. The answer is just covering the concrete use case.